# Fitting string literals for different string classes

Tags: string, templates, c++11, literals, prefix

### The problem

I am implementing a class where I want to let the user choose the string type (`std::string`, `std::wstring`, `std::u16string`, ...) via a template parameter. I currently fail to make the string literals *fit* the chosen string type: Once I decide for a literal prefix (`"hello"` vs. `L"hello"` vs. `u"hello"` vs. `U"hello"`), I get compilation errors for all incompatible string classes.

### Toy example

As an example, consider the following code (compile with `--std=c++11`):

```
#include <string>

template<typename StringType>
void hello_string()
{
    StringType result("hello");
}

int main()
{
    // works
    hello_string<std::string>();
    hello_string<std::basic_string<char>>();

    // the code below does not compile
    hello_string<std::wstring>();
    hello_string<std::basic_string<unsigned char>>();
    hello_string<std::u16string>();
}
```

Function `hello_string()` shows the essence of what I want to do: have a string type as template parameter, and assign string literals to variables of this type.

### Possible workaround

One way to overcome my problem would be to implement several specializations of the `hello_string()` function. The problem is that this would lead to several copies of each string literal - one for each string literal prefix. I think this is rather ugly, and there must be better way.

Another way could be to chose "normal" string literals as default values and have functions do a conversion to the different string types. While this would avoid code duplication, it would introduce unnecessary conversions of something that is actually constant.

Comment: `const char kHello[] = "hello"; StringType result(kHello, kHello + sizeof(kHello) - 1);` Only works for plain ASCII.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that this constructor type is common for all basic_strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make yourself a macro. First define a struct that wraps the char-choosing:

```
namespace details {

    template<typename T>
    struct templ_text;

    template<>
    struct templ_text <char>
    {
        typedef char char_type;
        static const char_type * choose(const char * narrow, const wchar_t * wide, const char16_t* u16, const char32_t* u32) { return narrow; }
        static char_type choose(char narrow, wchar_t wide, char16_t u16, char32_t u32) { return narrow; }
    };

    template<>
    struct templ_text < wchar_t >
    {
        typedef wchar_t char_type;
        static const char_type* choose(const char * narrow, const wchar_t * wide, const char16_t* u16, const char32_t* u32) { return wide; }
        static char_type choose(char narrow, wchar_t wide, char16_t u16, char32_t u32) { return wide; }
    };

    template<>
    struct templ_text < char16_t >
    {
        typedef char16_t char_type;
        static const char_type* choose(const char * narrow, const wchar_t * wide, const char16_t* u16, const char32_t* u32) { return u16; }
        static char_type choose(char narrow, wchar_t wide, char16_t u16, char32_t u32) { return u16; }
    };

    template<>
    struct templ_text < char32_t >
    {
        typedef char32_t char_type;
        static const char_type* choose(const char * narrow, const wchar_t * wide, const char16_t* u16, const char32_t* u32) { return u32; }
        static char_type choose(char narrow, wchar_t wide, char16_t u16, char32_t u32) { return u32; }
    };
}
```

Wrap it into a nice macro:

```
#define TEMPL_TEXT(Ch, txt) details::templ_text<Ch>::choose(txt, L##txt, u##txt, U##txt)
```

Then your function would be:

```
template<typename StringType>
void hello_string()
{
    StringType result(TEMPL_TEXT(typename StringType::value_type, "Hello"));
}
```

I think that unused copies of the string will be optimized away.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I knew there was a way to add literal prefixes with a macro, but I could not find a way to combine this with templates.